# Find and remove all getter method in eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, find, replace, eclipse-juno

How can I find all the getter methods in eclipse?

I tried get* with methods , but it will return all those non-getter method which starts with get,too. I want only getter methods.

**Edit:**
I want to remove all the getter methods from workspace.

Comment: because I'm curious - what's a non-getter that starts with 'get'? And how would one distinguish a 'getter' method from a non-getter method that starts with 'get'?

Comment: @Chris: `isXXX()` for booleans?

Comment: @PriyankDoshi: [What is your *actual* problem?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @thkala then how about those which starts with is ?

Comment: @thkala : I want to remove all the getter methods from workspace.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi: *why* do you want to do that? Because, quite honestly, blanket solutions like this are rarely the right thing to do...

Comment: @thkala - the question mentions that searching for 'get' is returning a non-getter that starts with 'get' - `isXXX` is a getter that does not start with get...

Comment: @Chris: A method which starts with get and takes arguments is not a getter. A method which starts with get and returns void is not a getter. A method which starts with get and is static is not a getter.

Comment: @thkala : I use setter based dependency injection in spring project. And I don't want getter to be present. I want it to be removed to prevent someone accidentally calling getter instead of using actual injected variable. Hope I made my point clear.

Comment: Why do you want to remove all getters? Very interesting...

Comment: @PriyankDoshi: I am not familiar with Spring, so I might be missing something here - why would calling the getter rather than using the field be a problem? I can understand why the *opposite* would be a problem, since that breaks about a million encapsulation properties, but in your case wouldn't the getter use the injected variable too?

Comment: @thkala : Yeah I do agree. Getter would use injected variable. But , the coding convention we follow , we don't use getter. We do use injected variable directly. Afterall , you are using the injected private variable within same class. So no one is breaking encapsulation rules also. They would come in picture when we access a variable outside that class . right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing what you want (whatever the reason), it is easier to use **Find Files**:

[image]

To narrow down, you could use **Selected resources** or **Enclosing projects**.

**Edit: Regex should be little different:** `(?s)(is|get)([a-zA-Z0-9]*\(\)\s*\{)`

Comment: Wouldn't this also match *calls* to getter methods?

Comment: That is better - can you modify it to deal with the brace (`{`) being on the next line?

Comment: I think , it would match all get* method ?

Comment: Made it multiline. getter methods have no arguments?

Comment: @asgoth: I would argue that getter methods have no arguments, yet unfortunately the inverse - that methods with no arguments are getters - is not generally true. I am still doubtful that what the OP wants to do is the right way and, even if it is, that it is actually worth it just to enforce some coding convention...

Comment: @asgoth: still, quite often a simple `grep` *is* the simplest solution around - +1...

Comment: @thkala: it's a very specific usecase. Normally it is the other way around: you have a method and you want to find its references. In other words, I wouldn't use it myself, but then I haven't found the need to find all getters ;)

Comment: @asgoth : lucky . you haven't found the need yet. :)

Comment: @thkala : It also looks clean to use someVariable.someMethod() rather getSomeVariable().someMethod.

Comment: @thkala : i agree that the getter based approach is common in non-spring based application . But here, with spring, we won't prefer that.

Comment: eh? spring uses beans extensively and you should therefore use getters/setters. It sounds like you're gonna be breaking encapsulation and tightly coupling your classes if you don't use the usual bean conventions.

Comment: @SteveAtkinson : Yeah spring does. But if i use setter based injection , would getter be ever used by spring?